# set inner div width to be equal to the width of the outer div

Tags: html, css

I have several div's absolutely positioned inside a parent div. I have set the fixed width to parent div. And the inner divs have the width set to 100%.

But the inner div's occupy whole browser width. I want the inner divs to be only as wide as parent div.

How can I achieve this? (Without changing absolute positioning)

A part of My HTMl:

```
<div class="holder">
    some</br>
    sample</br>
    text    
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent{
width:250px;
}

.holder {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
background-color: #ccc;
}
</div>
```

here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EUtLh/98/

Answer (score 2):

Set position relative or absolute to parent div

```
.parent {
    width:250px;
    positon: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

style the parent to have width of auto, this would wrap the parent's width to the inner div

```
.parent{
  width: auto;
}
```